# Kendo datasource adds itself an invalid aggregates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I recently updated to the most recent version of kendo (v2014.2.716).
And now, I get errors when receiving callbacks of grid datasources. It seems that the datasource has an aggregate, but the weird thing is, the aggregate it self is the function to get the aggregates...

The kendo datasource aggregate function is as follow :

```
function (val) {
    var that = this;
    if(val !== undefined) {
        that._query({ aggregate: val });
        return;
    }
    return that._aggregate;
}
```

If I call the aggregate function, I get an array of the aggregate function itself :

```
[
    function (val) {
        var that = this;
        if(val !== undefined) {
            that._query({ aggregate: val });
            return;
        }
        return that._aggregate;
    }
]
```

The datasource is created this way :

```
new kendo.data.DataSource({
    pageSize: 100,
    transport: {
        read: {
            async: true
            cache: false
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
            dataType: "json"
            type: "GET"
            url: "URL"
        }
    }
})
```

I've traced this back to this line in kendo.data.js line 2089 :

```
that._aggregate = options.aggregate;
```

Am I doing something wrong or I have some incompatibility ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you read their documentation on [aggregate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-aggregate.aggregate) definition? Aggregate is an `array` of `objects` not `functions`, that happens to have one member element also called `aggregate`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not trying to have any aggregates at all... The datasource seems to add it by itself... And it causes a call to toLowerCase of undefined since it cannot find the aggregate field (That I did not even request)

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle/JSBin? If so, I can take a look.